# Hide checkbox until mouseover and make it stay once checked WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, mouseover, multidatatrigger

The checkbox is invisible until I mouse over which is what I want, but now I want it to stay visible once it is checked. I've tried implementing a multi trigger, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Name="cbkSelect" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectedForOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True"></Condition>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True"></Condition>
                     </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                     </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                  </MultiDataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </CheckBox.Style>
      </CheckBox>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`MultiDataTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger?view=netcore-3.1) will only apply the setter when all conditions are met.

> Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data **meet a set** of conditions.

Apart from that, binding to the `DataGridRow` does not work, as it has no `IsChecked` property. Instead, add a [`Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.trigger?view=netcore-3.1) that acts on the `IsChecked` property of the associated `CheckBox`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </Trigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! Quick follow up question, if I wanted to instead show that a row is selected/unselected by changing the colors of the text (i.e. grey for unselected) instead of showing the checkbox, would I just change the property/value combination?

Comment: @AlexJohnson It depends on what you mean by selected. I guess you mean a custom selection, like with the `CheckBox`. In order to change the text color, you would need to set the `Foreground`. However, to apply this color also when a row or cell in a `DataGrid` is selected, you would need to change the control template, because that overrides your foreground color in the selected state, but this is way beyond the scope of a comment to answer, as it requires lots of code. Please consider asking a separate question for follow-ups like this.

Comment: got it, sorry about that! Posted as a separate question.